# How to add a subview to UITableView but not on the header?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableView with a custom tableViewHeader.

I want to add a subview (for a loading view), but I do not want to affect the header. It should be added to the section part only, so the controls remains active on the header, while the table reloads.

[image]

All the other resources that I found were to add the view to tableview header, or to section's header/footer or cell.contentView.

Comment: You can add loader on cell as     `cell.accessoryView = loaderView`

Comment: @Jack - I don't want to add the loader on a single cell. I need it to be on top of all cells.

Comment: You don't own the table view, so you should not add subviews to it. You should add your subview to the closest view above it in the hierarchy that you _do_ own, and just size it appropriately (you can constrain it using the table's header view, for example).

Comment: @JoshCaswell: this sounds good. However, I ended up by removing all the cells and displaying only one, with a loader. Place an answer so I can accept it.